# C#: html border to cells

Tags: c#, html

Have found the code in stackoverflow with my changes in it, the code doesn`t display cell borders, it only display table border, what am I missing here:

```
public void string displayHtmlTable()
{
    var table = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable();
    var mailMessage = new StringBuilder();
    string html;

    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow row;
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell cell;

    row = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
    cell = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();

    row.Cells.Add(new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "first", Align = ContentAlignment.TopCenter.ToString(), BorderColor = "Black" });
    row.Cells.Add(new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Second", Align = ContentAlignment.TopCenter.ToString(), BorderColor = "Black" });

    //row.Style.Add("border", "1px solid");
    row.Attributes.Add("border-bottom", "solid red 1px");

    table.Rows.Add(row);
    table.Style.Add("border", "1px solid");
    table.Style.Add("width", "auto");
    table.Style.Add("text-align", "center");

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        table.RenderControl(new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw));
        html = sw.ToString();
    }   
    //html - this doesn`t display borders.  
}
```

Please check and help.

Comment: The HtmlTableCell has a default border in the constructor so the code isn't changing the default.

Comment: The only border it displays is Table border. No cell border displayed or am not able to see it

Comment: It can be one pixel wide and you just can't see it.

Comment: How can I increase the pixel in the code?

Comment: See cell properties for table : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe adjust/set border width?